# Dynamically assigning variable with locals() isn't working in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, exec, locals

I have a recursive script that's scraping a JSON file for cars. At each recursive level, it gets a new variable added, and passes that (along with the other values) on to the recursive call, each time getting more and more detailed in the information. I tried to use `locals()` to dynamically assign a variable, but it remains `None` even after the call (I recall seeing that sometimes `locals()` is read only).

I tried using `eval()` as well, and it gives me the same issue (I know eval is not ideal). I'd ideally like to avoid using a dictionary, because that would require me to load it with values first, which seems like it has some unnecessary steps, but I'm open to anything at this point.

Example:

`scraper(manufacturer='Honda')` would scrape a JSON file of models, set `model='Accord'` and then recursively call

`scraper(manufacturer='Honda, model='Accord')` which scrapes a file of years, set's `year=2014` and recursively calls

`scraper(manufacturer='Honda', model='Accord', year='2014')` which is the base case

```
def scraper(self, manufacturers, model=None, year=None):

    if year:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s&model=%s&year=%s' % (url, manufacturer, model, year)
        return someFinalFunction()

    elif model:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s&model=%s' % (url, manufacturer, model)

    elif manufacturer:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s' % (url, manufacturer)

    j = getJSONFromUrl(scrapeurl)
    key, values = j.popitems()

    for value in values:
        locals()[key] = value
        return self.scraper(manufacturer, model, year, color)
```

I'd appreciate any input on how to handle this, I know Python always seems to have some clever ways of doing things, and I'm always learning more about it, so thank you in advance! I'm using Python3 in this example too, if that changes anything

Comment: Per the [docs for `locals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) - *"**Note** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."*

Comment: `locals()` is just a dictionary anyway.  Just make your own dictionary and all the values to that instead of to `locals`.

Comment: What is `for value in values: ... return` trying to achieve?

Comment: Eric, the JSON would have multiple values, so after the script does model='Accord' it would move on to model='Civic', etc,

Comment: `return` does not mean "move on", it means "finish"...

Comment: Oversight on my part, thanks for catching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps this will help:

```
def scraper(self, **kwargs):

    if kwargs.get('year') is not None:
        scrapeurl = '{0}&manufacturer={manufacturer}&model={model}&year={year}'
        return someFinalFunction() # not sure why this takes no arguments

    elif kwargs.get('model') is not None:
        scrapeurl = '{0}&manufacturer={manufacturer}&model={model}'

    elif kwargs.get('manufacturer') is not None:
        scrapeurl = '{0}&manufacturer={manufacturer}'

    else:
        raise KeyError

    j = getJSONFromUrl(scrapeurl.format(url, **kwargs))
    key, values = j.popitems()

    for value in values:
        kwargs[key] = value
        return self.scraper(**kwargs)
```

This uses Python's built-in functionality to treat arbitrary keyword arguments as a dictionary, along with more modern `str.format` string formatting, to dynamically handle the arguments you're looking for. The only difference is that you now need to call it:

```
instance.scraper(manufacturer='...')
```

rather than just

```
instance.scraper('...')
```

An example of the string formatting, mixing positional and keyword arguments:

```
>>> '{0}&manufacturer={manufacturer}'.format('foo', **{'manufacturer': 'bar'})
'foo&manufacturer=bar'
```

Comment: THe finalFunction takes no arguments because I cleaned up the code provided to keep it shorter and relevant to where the issue it, thanks for taking the time to go over though.

Comment: Also, didn't know about the modern str.format thing, pretty cool, thanks

Comment: @Parker in general, please be careful when cutting code down to ensure it stays comprehensible - I was also confused by the absence of `url` in scope!

Answer (score 2):

`locals()['key'] = value` should be `locals()[key] = value`

---

Better yet, use `**kwargs`:

```
def scraper(self, manufacturer, model=None, year=None):
    kwargs = dict(manufacturer=manufacturer, model=model, year=year)

    if year:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s&model=%s&year=%s' % (url, manufacturer, model, year)
        return someFinalFunction()

    elif model:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s&model=%s' % (url, manufacturer, model)

    elif manufacturer:
        scrapeurl = '%s&manufacturer=%s' % (url, manufacturer)

    j = getJSONFromUrl(scrapeurl)
    key, values = j.popitems()

    for value in values:
        kwargs[key] = value
        return self.scraper(**kwargs)
```

Comment: The 'key' was a typo, my bad. Also, why was this downvoted, can whoever did this please explain why you did this, and why his method may not be ideal?